# Significant t-value but bayes factor showing favour towards null

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, brms

I am currently trying to build linear mixed-effect model to compare continuous dependent variables between categorical independent variables (like conducting ANOVA), but with random factors (to remove potential extraneous variable), and calculate its Bayes factor to have double approach in hypothesis testing (if t-value is smaller than 1.96, meaning not significant, bayes factor will show if there is insufficient evidence or favour towards null hypothesis).

**When I create and run linear mixed-effect model (using buildmer function), it shows  significant t-value. However, bayes factor (calculated by creating model using brm function and run hypothesis function using the brm model) is very small, showing favour towards null.**

I checked if all variables and naming are correct, but they all are. Also, this is happening in only one specific dependent variable, and when I run exactly the same code with other dependent variables, they work fine.

I do not know why t-value and bayes factor are showing such contradictory result. Is there any reason why this is happening (any explanation or solution to this issue is appreciated)? Thank you for your support!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What kind of prior do you have? For instance, if you go to the extreme case where all of the prior probability is on the "null" value, you cannot shift your posterior distribution away from that. A strong prior distribution that is less extreme (just concentrated around that null value, even if there is density elsewhere) will be able to be shifted away from the prior, but it will take a lot of evidence.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply! My prior is uniform for each fixed effect (normal(0,1)). The estimate is 0.006134, is this the reason why? In this case, what should I do? (Also, any detailed explanation on prior is appreciated because I am quite a beginner in building linear mixed effect model with buildmer package.